# Laravel Relationship not working with belongsTo

Tags: laravel, model, foreign-keys, relationship, relation

**Hello Guys, I am just passing my query to notification blade, but its gave error. I dont know what i did wrong with bellow code. If you guys fix this issue i will be very glad. Thanks in advance**

**Notification seen model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Backend;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class notificationseen extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'notificationseens';

    public function Notification()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Notification::class, 'notificationID');
    }
}
```

**Notification Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Backend;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notification extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'notifications';

    public function notificationseen()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(notificationseen::class, 'notificationID');
    }
}
```

**View Blade**

```
 @foreach( $notification as $notify )

          @if($notify->Notification->seen == 0)
          <!-- Single Notification --><a href="{{ route('singlenotify', $notify->id) }}" id="notifysee" data-id="{{ $notify->id }}">
            
            <div class="alert unread custom-alert-3 alert-primary" role="alert"><i class="bi bi-bell mt-0"></i>
              <div class="alert-text w-75">
                <h6 class="text-truncate">{{ $notify->name }}</h6><span class="text-truncate">{{ $notify->description }}</span>
              </div>
            </div></a>
          @else
          <!-- Single Notification --><a href="{{ route('singlenotify', $notify->id) }}">
          <div class="alert custom-alert-3 alert-primary" role="alert"><i class="bi bi-bell mt-0"></i>
              <div class="alert-text w-75">
              <h6 class="text-truncate">{{ $notify->name }}</h6><span class="text-truncate">{{ $notify->description }}</span>
              </div>
            </div></a>

          @endif
        @endforeach
```

**Table structure**

```
 $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('userid');
            $table->integer('notificationID');
            $table->integer('seen')->default('0')->comment("0 for unseen 1 for seen");
            $table->timestamps();
```

**Can you please help me out. I cant see any issue but its me error "Attempt to read property "seen" on null"**

Comment: Both models are returning `belongsTo` realtionship. the `Noticiation model` has to include your relationship whether it is a `hasOne/hasMany/or morph...`. `return $this->hasMany(notificationseen::class, 'notificationID');` should be fine in the `Notification model` [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to add an isset to avoid the error :

```
@if(isset($notify->Notification->seen) && $notify->Notification->seen == 0)
   (...)
@else
   (...)
@endif
```

EDIT : in your code, you defined 2 `belongsTo` methods, but according to the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship), you must define a `hasOne` method and the inverse of it, the `belongsTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some things:

1. I would use `belongsTo` in the `notificationseen` class unless one `notificationseen` could have more than one `Notifications` to belong to ;)
2. Do a `Notification` have more than one `notificationseen` references? I do not think so, so in your `Notification` change the reference to `hasOne`.
3. In your blade, use `@if($notify->notificationseen->seen == 0)` or you call better "Notification::**with('notificationseen')**->get()" in your controller and then pass it to your view.